# 英語が残っている:「ユーザープロフィール」-「信用度」-「グラフ」

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 英語

以下の信用度グラフの横軸、縦軸のタイトルが英語のままです。

[image: 指摘用画像]

Comment: なるほど、どこまで調整をできるかを相談します。第三者のライブラリーだと思うので、限界があるかもしれません。とりあえず確認してみます。

Comment: マイナーな箇所なので調整が出来なければ英語のままでもそれほど問題はないと思います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

指摘した箇所が翻訳されていることを確認しました。